# how to change a css background-image with root

Tags: javascript, css

I have a css var

--image-email: pictures/email_light.png;

and in CSS I have

```
.image_email {
    height: 105px;
    width: 105px;
    background-image: url(var(--image-email));
}
```

which is not working
and i want to know if there is a way to change an image with root or must i try js?

Comment: Your code looks good so far. Make sure to **URL-encode** your link to your image `"url('url_to_/pictures/email_light.png')")`

Answer (score 2):

You need set to root value with function `url()`. And yes, you can change the image without JS, just by rewriting initial url in another class. [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-hypatia-pgwxz?file=/index.html)

**CSS**

```
:root {
  --image-email: url('pictures/email_light.png');
}

.new-image {
  --image-email: url('pictures/email_light-new.png');
}

.image_email {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background-image: var(--image-email);
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}

:root {
  --image-email: url('https://plchldr.co/i/100x100?&bg=%22edffab%22&fc=%222b3d41%22&text=100x100');
}

.another-image {
  --image-email: url('https://plchldr.co/i/100x100?&bg=89608E&fc=fff&text=100x100');
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.image_email {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-image: var(--image-email);
}
```

```html
<div class="image_email"></div>
<div class="image_email another-image"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to nice answer from @ЖнецЪ

Two ways how to change background-img:

1. **Add/Remove Classes (@ЖнецЪ)**:
   `.classList.add('another-image')`
2. **setProperty** (set CSS variable directly in JS):
   `.style.setProperty("--image-email", "url('https://....')")`

Try and **Run code snippet**:

```js
// Option 1
function option1Y() {
  document.getElementById('sample_box_1').classList.remove('another-image');

  document.getElementById('button_1_yellow').disabled = true;
  document.getElementById('button_1_purple').disabled = false;
};

function option1P() {
  document.getElementById('sample_box_1').classList.add('another-image');

  document.getElementById('button_1_yellow').disabled = false;
  document.getElementById('button_1_purple').disabled = true;
};

// Option 2
function option2Y() {
  document.getElementById('sample_box_2').style.setProperty("--image-email", "url('https://plchldr.co/i/100x100?&bg=%22edffab%22&fc=%222b3d41%22&text=100x100')");

  document.getElementById('button_2_yellow').disabled = true;
  document.getElementById('button_2_purple').disabled = false;
};

function option2P() {
  document.getElementById('sample_box_2').style.setProperty("--image-email", "url('https://plchldr.co/i/100x100?&bg=89608E&fc=fff&text=100x100')");

  document.getElementById('button_2_yellow').disabled = false;
  document.getElementById('button_2_purple').disabled = true;
};
```

```css
:root {
  --image-email: url('https://plchldr.co/i/100x100?&bg=%22edffab%22&fc=%222b3d41%22&text=100x100');
}

.another-image {
  --image-email: url('https://plchldr.co/i/100x100?&bg=89608E&fc=fff&text=100x100');
}

body {
  text-align: center;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}
button {
  margin: 1em;
  color: blue;
}
button:disabled {
  color: gray;
}

.image_email {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 1em calc(50% - 50px);
  background-image: var(--image-email);
}
```

```html
<h1>Changing CSS variables<br>(custom properties):</h1>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <h3>by adding / removing a Class in JS:</h3>
      <p>.classList.add('another-image')</p>
      <button id='button_1_yellow' onclick="option1Y()" disabled>Yellow</button>
      <button id='button_1_purple' onclick="option1P()">Purple</button>
      <div id='sample_box_1' class="image_email"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <h3>by setting CSS variables directly in JS:</h3>
      <p>.style.setProperty("--image-email", "url('https://....')")</p>
      <button id='button_2_yellow' onclick="option2Y()" disabled>Yellow</button>
      <button id='button_2_purple' onclick="option2P()">Purple</button>
      <div id='sample_box_2' class="image_email"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

More details at [MDN Using CSS custom properties (variables)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties)

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who want to replace CSS background with base64 encoded pics - here an idea including some theme switching

```
//declare an object for your themes - so that the values can easily switched
var myTheme: {
    dark: {
        'img-magnifier': 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw....=='
    },
    regular: {
        'img-magnifier': 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw....=='
    }
}
    
let themeMode = config.darkMode ? 'dark' : 'regular';
//we just gonna take the values from the correct object (dark or regular?)
$(':root').css({'--img-magnifier': 'url(' +myTheme[themeMode]['img-magnifier'] +')'});
//from up to here - this DOM element/value is been stored in root and can be taken from any CSS


/* CSS - this is the part in your CSS */
.myImageMagnifier {
    background-image: var(--img-magnifier) !important;
}
.someOtherPic {
    background-image: var(--img-magnifier);
}
```